# Fazer pequenas edições

Tags: debate, edição

Tenho essa dúvida há muito tempo e hoje me deparei com 2 situações.

Editei o título de duas perguntas, porém, em ambos os caso foi algo muito pequeno.
Apenas corrigi a palavra "query" para "queries" pois o sentido do título estava no plural.
Alguns minutos depois apareceu uma outra pergunta com exatamente o mesmo problema, porém ao contrário. Estava descrito como "querie" e corrigi para "query".

OK, acho que nesses casos pode até ser válido corrigir.

A dúvida é referente a casos onde falta uma acentuação numa palavra:
O correto seria "Passar controle para **parâmetro**" na pergunta:
[Passar controle como parametro](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/59031/passar-controle-como-parametro)

Resumindo, é válido ficar editando e corrigindo coisas pequenas dessa forma?

*Publiquei essa pergunta por engano no SOPT beta.
Marquei para remover e publiquei aqui no meta.

Answer (score 10):

Isso daí frequentemente causa polêmica, mas eu pessoalmente acho perfeitamente válido. Se você está disposto a voluntariamente usar parte do seu tempo para localizar e corrigir erros de digitação e acentuação por menor que sejam sem ganhar nada com isso, então, desde que as suas alterações sejam corretas, acho que todos aqui só terão a agradecer e não deveria haver motivo para alguém reclamar disso.

Comment: Eu concordo, e vou além: mesmo que a pessoa ganhe algo com isso (pontos por edições sugeridas), se está melhorando a postagem, é válido. No SOen é muito mais fácil abusar disso do que aqui. Aqui precisamos de mais gente editando. Se houver abuso, aí a gente vê como lidar.

Comment: Eu pensei em sugerir uma opção onde a pessoa que edita pode escolher recusar o recebimento de pontos. Exemplo, eu faço uma pequena edição, e na hora de justificar o motivo, ter opçao para escolha "gostaria de não receber pontos". Obviamente a maioria não vai escolher isso né.. rsrs Mas eu gostaria de ter .. Eu me sinto incomodado em fazer coisas tão pequenas e receber um ponto por isso e, também para não parecer que estou fazendo essas edições para receber migalhas de modo fácil.

Comment: @DanielOmine Isso daí seria para sugerir lá no metão, mas não acho que iriam gostar da sua ideia. Além disso, depois que você atinge 1000 pontos de reputação, suas edições são aprovadas automaticamente, mas você não recebe mais ponto nenhum por elas.

Comment: Obrigado Victor. Não sabia desse esquema dos 1000 pontos.